# Compressed Oops and Java versions

Tags: java

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html) I read this sentence:

> Compressed oops is supported and enabled by default in Java SE 6u23
>   and later. In Java SE 7, use of compressed oops is the default for
>   64-bit JVM processes when -Xmx isn't specified and for values of -Xmx
>   less than 32 gigabytes.

but I don't understand the difference between Java SE 6u23 and Java 7.
If it is written that compressed oops is supported and enabled by default in Java SE 6u23 and later why is also said that it's defaulted to on with Java SE 7 for 64 JVM?

Comment: I think `and later` refers to Java 6, actually Java SE 6u45 (this option exists since Java SE 6u23),

Comment: But also in Java 7 on 32 bit JVM is this flag on? And is Java SE 6u23 referred to a 64 bit JVM?

Comment: @xdevel2000, Compressed Oops are only for 64 bits to save 4 bytes per pointer ([which works up to about 32Gb](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/02/35gb-heap-less-32gb-java-jvm-memory-oddities/).)